# Memory layout of argc, argv, envp

Tags: c, linux

From what I understand, the values of the environment variables are in memory directly after the NULL-terminated `argv` values. Beyond the env variables, `auxv` is present.

How exactly are the environment variables laid out – where is this layout specified / documented? And what systems does it apply to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple answer will be: the layout of the stack on program invocation is defined by the binary format definitions (such as ELF spec: http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/abi386-4.pdf, check out figure 3-31 for the initial stack layout on `exec`).

As Linux is not limited to the ELF executables and can support multiple binary formats using its `binfmt` interpreter framework, the actual handling of `argv`/`envp` data happens in 2 stages.

First, when `sys_execve` system call is invoked, the kernel will create a virtual memory mapping for the new process stack. Then it will use a page or few (up to the 32 pages arbitrary limit) from the bottom of the stack to store a copy of the `argv`/`envp` parameters supplied:

```
bprm->exec = bprm->p;
retval = copy_strings(bprm->envc, envp, bprm);
if (retval < 0)
    goto out;

retval = copy_strings(bprm->argc, argv, bprm);
if (retval < 0)
    goto out;
```

(http://code.metager.de/source/xref/linux/stable/fs/exec.c#1502)

During the second stage, `bprm` object is passed to the `binfmt` interpreter (together with associated memory mappings). The interpreter, beside other things, will push additional info to the stack, including the argument/environment entry counts and pointers. For elf executables it will happen in `create_elf_tables`:

```
/* Now, let's put argc (and argv, envp if appropriate) on the stack */
if (__put_user(argc, sp++))
    return -EFAULT;
argv = sp;
envp = argv + argc + 1;

/* Populate argv and envp */
p = current->mm->arg_end = current->mm->arg_start;
while (argc-- > 0) {...
```

(http://code.metager.de/source/xref/linux/stable/fs/binfmt_elf.c#293)

The interpreter here is actually building the structure outlined in figure 3-31 in the spec linked above.

Comment: So just to clarify, it sounds like it's just ELF binaries are the ones I'd expect to to have this layout?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the particular binary format. A.out is different, so are "flat" executables.